# How to load pulseaudio module programatically with libpulse?

Tags: linux, audio, pulseaudio

How to load/unload pulseaudio module programatically with stable api?

There is a way with pulseaudio Dbus api but this api is no longer maintained.

> The D-Bus interface has no stability guarantees, which means that the
> interface may change in incompatible ways at any time. You have been
> warned. Don't use this for anything important. Use libpulse instead.
>
> In practice the interface has stayed very stable, however, like dead
> things tend to do.

I want to load module with pulseaudio C api but I can't found it.
How to do it?

I would like to develop a application that be able to stream computer sound to video or voice call on Linux.

It need load pulseaudio module (Probably `module-null-sink` and `module-loopback`, `module-combine` are required) when the application is running, and unload these modules when its application stopped.

Comment: First thing I'd do is to look at the source code of `pacmd` and `pactl`, and see how they do it.

Comment: did you try to use the system( ) function or popen() if you need the response?